# Where do I download all of the necessary classes to write Hadoop MapReduce jobs?

Tags: api, class, download, hadoop, mapreduce

I've recently started working with Hadoop and have been learning how to write MapReduce jobs.  All over the internet, I can find examples and tutorials for writing MapReduce jobs, but they all include import statements that go something like 'import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;'. I cannot find where to download any of those classes and I can't even begin writing jobs until I do find them.  Where can I download the necessary plug-in?

I've tried the plug-in that comes along with a Hadoop download and I've also tried a MapReduce plug-in for Eclipse distributed by IBM, but neither has worked.  Where can I download the correct one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I assume you're using java...

Here you can download it.
http://hadoop.apache.org/common/releases.html#Download

If you're on 20.X, you'll just need to import (putting it into your classpath) the hadoop-0.20.X-core.jar in the "root" folder. If > 20.X you have to use three jars: hadoop-common-0.21.0.jar, hadoop-hdfs-0.21.0.jar, hadoop-mapred-0.21.0.

Obviously you have to replace the 'x' with the suffix of the version you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Maven repositories for that. I'm assuming you are using Java and Maven.
Repos are here: https://repository.cloudera.com/index.html